# How to integrate swagger-ui with Django Rest Framework and Django-Rest-framwork-Swagger?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-rest-swagger

I am writing a Django app that exposes an API via DRF. Normally, I would generate the schema from code and expose the API docs via swagger-ui and the django rest framework swagger plugin for Django. The plugin uses 2 renderes to do so like:

`schema_view = get_schema_view(
    title='app api title',
    renderer_classes=[OpenAPIRenderer, SwaggerUIRenderer]
)`

My use case is a bit different this time. What I am trying to do is to render an already existing swagger.yml (I dont want to generate this dynamically from code). I guessed one needs to inject the existing swagger.yml into the SwaggerUIRenderer, but I failed to do so...

Is there any way to do this via the rest swagger plugin?

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a definition file you don't need to use django_rest_swagger plugin, you can simply use Swagger-UI as recommended in this iusse.

https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-swagger/issues/567

Comment: so youre basically saying it is not possible, as you can just use it via static resources?